# How to marshall array of structs in C#?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I've the following structure in C#:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECORD
{
    public uint m1;
    public uint m2;
    public uint m3;
}
```

I need too pass an **array** (fixed length) of these structs over to native Code, which writes some data to these structures. The array is allocated in C# and passed over to the C dll. I declared the imported function as:

```
[DllImport("marshall.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void doIt(RECORD[] dataRecord);
```

but I don't get any data back. I already tried the PInvoke Interop Assistant. Should I use IntPtr here? Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Here is the C# code to call the native function:

```
RECORD[] rec = new RECORD[256];
doIt(rec);
// values of rec are all zero here
```

Here is the C function:

```
int doIt(RECORD* rec)
{
    // deref pointer and write some data
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm far from a P/Invoke expert, but I wonder if making it an in/out parameter might help:

```
DllImport("marshall.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void doIt([In, Out] RECORD[] dataRecord);
```

I wouldn't have *expected* that to be necessary though, as with `LayoutKind.Sequential` I'd hope that your struct is already a blittable type, and that the array would be blittable too.

Comment: That did the trick, thx. Are there other places where these keywords are used? I've never seen them before

Comment: From MSDN:
[refering to arrays of blittable types]
However, these types are actually marshaled as In parameters, and you must apply the InAttribute and OutAttribute attributes if you want to marshal the argument as an In/Out parameter.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me - and ended a two hour struggle to get this done.