# How to marshal an array of structure In C#?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have to call a C++ dll in C#. And the header of the dll is as following(simplified):

//Header of C++

```
struct vector
{
    float x;
    float y;

    vector()
    {}

    vector(float x0, float y0)
    {
        x = x0;
        y = y0;
    }
};

struct unmanaged_struct
{
    int int_var;
    float float_var;
    char* chars_var;
    vector vector_var;

    unmanaged_struct(int i, float f, char* ch, float vec_x, float vec_y) 
    {
        int_var = i;
        float_var = f;
        chars_var = ch;
        vector_var = vector(vec_x, vec_y);
    }
};
```

// this function is used to output all the variable values of the struct instance

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )  void unmanagedstruct_summary(unmanaged_struct* us_list, int length);
```

And I defined following class in C#

//CSharp

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Vector
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Vector(float f1, float f2)
    {
        x = f1;
        y = f2;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class UnmanagedStruct 
{ 
    public int int_var;
    public float float_var;
    public string char_var;
    public Vector vector_var;

    public UnmanagedStruct(int i, float f, string s, Vector vec)
    {
        this.int_var = i;
        this.float_var = f;
        this.char_var = s;
        this.vector_var = vec;
    }
}

class UnmanagedDllCallTest
{
    [DllImport("unmanageddll.dll", EntryPoint = "unmanagedstruct_summary")]
    public  static extern void unmanagedstruct_summary([Out]UnmanagedStruct[] usList, int length);    

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    
        UnmanagedStruct[] usList = new UnmanagedStruct[1];
        usList[0] = new UnmanagedStruct(1, 1.0f, "aa", new Vector(10, 1));       
        usList[1] = new UnmanagedStruct(2, 2.0f, "ba", new Vector(20, 2));  
        UnmanagedDllCallTest.unmanagedstruct_summary(usList, 2);
}
```

And the output is as following:

> unmanaged_struct summary:
>
> 0
>
> 1.12104e-044
>
> Unhandled Exception:
> System.AccessViolationException:
> Attempted to read or write  protected
> memory. This is often an indication
> that other memory is corrupt.    at
> callunmanageddll.UnmanagedDllCallTest.unmanagedstruct_summary(UnmanagedStr
> uct[] usList, Int32 length)    at
> callunmanageddll.Program.Main(String[]
> args) in c:\users\dynaturtle\docume
> nts\visual studio
> 2010\Projects\callunmanageddll\callunmanageddll\Program.cs:lin
> e 68

The C++ dll is OK as I have written test in C++ and the function works well. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729514/how-to-marshall-array-of-structs-in-c) but it seems the solution didn't work in my case. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. There is a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx).

So you would have to change the signature of the method from out structure array to out IntPtr. However, you need to know the size of the buffer being passed out.

```
public struct Vector
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

}

public struct UnmanagedStruct 
{ 
    public int int_var;
    public float float_var;
    public string char_var;
    public Vector vector_var;

}

class UnmanagedDllCallTest
{
    [DllImport("unmanageddll.dll", EntryPoint = "unmanagedstruct_summary")]
    public static extern void unmanagedstruct_summary([Out] IntPtr ptr, int length);    

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        UnmanagedStruc st;
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, st);
        // increment ptr and move forward
    }

}
```

Comment: PtrToStructure is used for a single struct, but I would pass an array of structure to the dll export function

Comment: I have put a sample code. It is the matter of looping and changing pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

First: Vector and UnmanagedStruct should be structs, not classes.

Comment: But what is the difference between structs and class?

Answer (score 0):

JIC I'd share my approach. Perhaps this is not an expected answer by at one time I spend a time to resolve my issue.

I have the following structure to expose some data from DLL.

```
//C++ code
    struct State
    {
        const wchar_t * name;
        unsigned int state; 
    };

APIENTRY bool get_states(H_PRCSR, MacroState *, const int sz); //pay attention, function accepts already allocated array and size for it
```

To accept this data From C++ I can do this way

```
std::vector<State> states(desired_size);
get_states(hparser, &states[0], states.size());
```

To do the same on C# I used the following way

```
//C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Status
{
   public IntPtr name;
   public uint state;

   public string getName()
   {
     if (name == IntPtr.Zero) return "<no-value>";
     return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(name);
   }
}

//And import function...

[DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
private static extern bool get_states(IntPtr p, [Out]MacroFlag[] flags, int flags_size);

//And simple decoder
public static Status[] getAll(IntPtr p, int size)
{
   var results = new Status[size];

   get_states(p, results, size);

   return results;
}
```

As, I saw the are different approaches to do this. This is one of them. And it works for me. Perhaps, this post will not resolve the issue but will be a good point to start