# Use C# array crashed when access element in c++ api

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I have 2 arrays in C# and one API in c++ (provided library, no source)

```
public struct POS_DATA_2D
{
    public UInt32 u32_opt;
    public Int32 i32_x;
    public Int32 i32_y;
    public Int32 i32_theta;
}
public struct PNT_DATA_2D
{
    public UInt32 u32_opt;
    public Int32 i32_x;
    public Int32 i32_y;
    public Int32 i32_theta;
    public Int32 i32_acc;
    public Int32 i32_dec;
    public Int32 i32_vi; 
    public Int32 i32_vm;
    public Int32 i32_ve;
}
int cnt = 58;
POS_DATA_2D[] pPosarr = new POS_DATA_2D[cnt];
PNT_DATA_2D[] pPntarr = new PNT_DATA_2D[cnt];
```

The problem is when I call the below API the program crashed. I guessed it accessed array element which isn't correct.

```
ADCNC_W32.APS168.VelocityPlanning(cnt, ref pPosarr[0], ref pPntarr[0]);
```

The description of that API

```
 [DllImport("ADCNC.dll")]public static extern Int32 
VelocityPlanning(
    System.UInt32 PosCount    // [IN ] position array count, [1,4294967295]
 ,  ref POS_DATA_2D PosArray    // [IN ] position array start pointer, [!NULL]
 ,  ref PNT_DATA_2D PntArray    // [OUT] point array start pointer, [!NULL]
 );
```

Please help me to point out the incorrect points. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to marshal an array of structure In C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335481/how-to-marshal-an-array-of-structure-in-c)

Comment: Can you post the C method declaration so we can check if the DllImport is written correctly?

Comment: This is structure in C++
  I32 __stdcall
VelocityPlanning( U32               PosCount    , POS_DATA_2D*PosArray, PNT_DATA_2D*      PntArray  );

Comment: That C++ doesn't look like it is accepting an array.  It looks like it is accepting a single POS_DATA_2D object, passed by value on the stack.  But your C# code clearly is passing a pointer to an array element.  I can't tell entirely without seeing the definition of POS_DATA_2D in the C++ code.  Can you post that too?  Also: Make sure you check the structure size and alignment.

Comment: This is truct of POS_DATA_2D
    public struct POS_DATA_2D
    {
    public UInt32 u32_opt;
    public Int32 i32_x;  
    public Int32 i32_y;
    public Int32 i32_theta;
    }