# C# : Unmanaged delegate in structs, and other unmanaged problems by wrapping the vulkan API dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, vulkan

I'm trying to use the new vulkan API in my C# program. As we only have an access to the header file, I copied the code and I adapted it in an unsafe class to wrap it :

```
unsafe public static class Vk {
    ...
    public delegate void* PFN_vkAllocationFunction(...);
    public delegate void* PFN_vkReallocationFunction(...);
    public delegate void PFN_vkFreeFunction(...);
    public delegate void PFN_vkInternalAllocationNotification(...);
    public delegate void PFN_vkInternalFreeNotification(...);

    public struct AllocationCallbacks {
        void* pUserData;
        PFN_vkAllocationFunction pfnAllocation;
        PFN_vkReallocationFunction pfnReallocation;
        PFN_vkFreeFunction pfnFree;
        PFN_vkInternalAllocationNotification pfnInternalAllocation;
        PFN_vkInternalFreeNotification pfnInternalFree;
    }
    ...

}
```

All PFN_xxx was originally function pointers in the header, and I intuitively rewrote them as delegate. So, for the moment, it's working. However, late in the code, I have the following function, imported from the dll, which make an error :

```
[DllImport("Dll\vulkan-1.dll", EntryPoint = "VkCreateInstance")]
public extern static Result CreateInstance(
    InstanceCreateInfo* pCreateInfo,
    AllocationCallbacks* pAllocator,   <- error here
    Instance* pInstance);
```

The error is the **CS0208**, described by the following message : **"Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Vk.AllocationCallbacks')"**
By googling a little, I understood that AllocationCallbacks is managed, because of delegates in it. So how can I solve this problem ? I found no satisfying answers on the net, and I tried to marshal delegates in my struct as unmanaged function pointers (like this), but it seems to doesn't work, the compiler keep the error.

```
public struct AllocationCallbacks {
        void* pUserData;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        PFN_vkAllocationFunction pfnAllocation;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        PFN_vkReallocationFunction pfnReallocation;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        PFN_vkFreeFunction pfnFree;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        PFN_vkInternalAllocationNotification pfnInternalAllocation;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        PFN_vkInternalFreeNotification pfnInternalFree;
    }
```

---

Here is another problem : I have a struct in which fixed-size arrays of struct are defined. Original declaration was :

```
typedef struct VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties {
    uint32_t        memoryTypeCount;
    VkMemoryType    memoryTypes[VK_MAX_MEMORY_TYPES];
    uint32_t        memoryHeapCount;
    VkMemoryHeap    memoryHeaps[VK_MAX_MEMORY_HEAPS];
} VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties;
```

And I just translated in this way :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties {
    uint memoryTypeCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_MEMORY_TYPES)]
    MemoryType[] memoryTypes;
    uint memoryHeapCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_MEMORY_HEAPS)]
    MemoryHeap[] memoryHeaps;
}
```

But again, I have the same problem, the famous CS0208 error, because of the following function import :

```
[DllImport("Dll\vulkan-1.dll", EntryPoint = "VkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties")]
public extern static void GetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(
     PhysicalDevice physicalDevice,
     PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties* pMemoryProperties);   <-error here
```

And this time, the error is because of fixed-size arrays. Any idea ?

Thank you for all your help !

Comment: [Here's some info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729514) that could help when marshalling structs in C#. As for the callbacks, `delegate`s are complex C# objects; they cannot be marshalled as simple C/C++ function pointers. Indeed, given that you're using C#, it'd probably be best to just pass NULL for the allocation callbacks. Just let the implementation allocate this stuff.

Comment: As Nicol said, passing in a null would probably be the best bet really. C# is managed and as far as I am aware, passing null into the allocationCallback just tells Vulkan to handle the memory management itself, which in a c# world would be what you would want anyway? I guess?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @NicolBolas and Keithin8a. Indeed, I don't want to do my own memory management. So, I was able to solve the first problem, by replacing my delegates by a UIntPtr. No when I call my function, I simply send a "nullptr" as a parameter, to replace AllocationCallbacks pointer. However I didn't find any solution to solve the array's problem.

Comment: I've a question. Is transform my struct to a class and take a reference instance as a parameter going to solve my problem ? As only reference of classes are passed to a function, and not the instance itself, this maybe should work. I'll try.

Comment: A class is still a managed type, so it can have extra hidden members that the garbage collector uses. Passing that off to a C function which doesn't know about the extra members will not work well...

Comment: If you're really determined, the [Marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a whole bunch of conversion methods, like GetFunctionPointerForDelegate, etc.